# What files can I safely enable NTFS compression for on Windows 7/8 USB bootable drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb, ntfs, compression

The title says it all. I am just a few MB short of copying the needed files to a USB flash drive I intend to use for installing Windows. I have marked the partition as active. I was wondering if I can safely enable NTFS compression for the installation files. Certainly the .WIM files won't gain much from the compression but there are plenty of .dll, .exe and text files in the sources directory and others that could be easily compressed.

Are there files that are safe to compress? Some that I should avoid compressing?

Comment: NTFS will only compress files it can compress.  You can compress everything if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When considering compression for small files, keep in Mind the NTFS cluster size of 4K: Files, that are below 4K and can not be compressed enough to fit entirely into the MFT record (i.e. more than a few byte) will use 4K before and after. A file of 7K with a compression rate of less than 1.8 will also use 8K before and after.

Text files will benefit most from compression, as they allow for a high compression rate, executables will benefit much less.

For a bootable drive, it might be much easier to just leave out some files - do you need `notepad.exe` and friends? Do you need all locales in `boot`?

**Edit**

As @Goyuix tested, the EFI bootloader (bootmgr.efi) has to remain uncompressed. This is to be expected, as it is not read by Windows, but by the EFI firmware, which knows nothing about compressed files.

The same holds true for the classic bootloader (bootmgr), which is read by BIOS, again knowing nothing oof file system compression.

Both firmware dialects just read a consecutive length of bytes into memory, then transfer control to them, which would obviously not work, if they are compressed.

Comment: The EFI bootloader doesn’t matter with NTFS because it won’t ever be used. ;)

Comment: @DanielB - Goyuix tried it, and bootmgr.efi has to stay uncompressed. It might be called from the first-stage bootloader in the EFI system partition, I don't know.

Comment: Who knows how he came to this conclusion. Considering how Setup still boots after removing the file it can’t possibly be relevant. Of course, when using FAT32 to be UEFI-bootable... you can’t compress it anyway. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Zip, gzip, LZH and other common compression schemes are lossless and reconstitute the file *verbatim*, so it is *safe* to compress anything, but as you implied, some files are already compressed, e.g. DOCX, XLSX, JPEG, MP3 and MP4, so you would gain little or nothing for those. See [Why don't some files compress very much?](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/104).

[BTW, JPEG and the Motion Picture (MP) compression *are* lossy schemes, which is why high-end cameras can save RAW data, as well.]

Comment: I appreciate the information, but this really doesn't answer the question of can I safely enable NTFS compression for the boot & install files.

Comment: A flash drive does not have a boot record *per se* unless you are making **bootable media**. Nowhere in your question do you state so. Reword your question to be specific.

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear. This is for bootable media to install Windows.

Comment: In that case, **any** encryption is problematical. Boot media, by definition, has to be able to open and install all files. If one arbitrarily compresses a file, whether text (which might be instructions used during deployment), or anything else, **how would the installation algorithm "know" that the file must be unpacked?** It would be simpler to *omit* a file you know is not used on your PC, e.g. a foreign driver, though even that might cause a failure.